# Why have a constructor and main method in same class

Tags: java

Why would you ever need to have a constructor in your class that contains `public static void main (String[] args){}`?

Why not have a separate class with the constructor instead and instantiate it?

Comment: A constructor can't contain a method. You mean both the constructor and the main-method in one **class**?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**`main()` method is the entry point for any program** in java. This is the method which is invoked by the JVM to execute the program.

**Every class including abstract classes has a constructor**. Even if you don't declare one explicitly, compiler will add a default constructor. The `main()` method has to belong to some public class (which will always have a constructor). Yes generally it is preferable to design another class which has all the programming logic and just instantiate this class in the main class i.e. the one with `main()` method in it.

But you can also have a class with `main` method which creates object of its own class (because **you cannot access instance members from static methods**).

Comment: you're right. see for example [`new SampleMain().doMain(args);`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kohsuke/args4j/args4j-2.0.16/args4j/examples/SampleMain.java)

Answer (score 8):

Method `public static void main(String[] args)` does not create instance of your class. But constructor does.

Having `main(String[])` method in several classes help to test functionality of a particular class in a big application.

Comment: Having `JUnit` or other unit tests help to test functionality of a particular class. Spurious `main` test entry points mostly helps to test the patience of coworkers foolish enough to bother running them.

Comment: JUnit cannot cover all situations when you need to test your applications.

Answer (score 7):

Constructors and the `main` method serve two different purposes.

Constructors allow **creation** of instances of a given Class, whereas the `main` method merely allows for a **potential entry point** for starting your program.

Furthermore you can have multiple constructors for a given class (accepting zero or more parameters), but only one main method (in a given class).

The main difference though is my first point - they serve different purposes.  One is an entry point to start a program, the other is explicitly there to allow for creation of instances of a class.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't think this will be constructive...

Some programmers like to place a `main` "test" program inside of the class itself to construct and use it. Some professors like to be faux-OOP by constructing an object and having it do the work.

...neither are strong patterns worthy of emulating in my personal opinion.